# Method in defined class not visible

Tags: objective-c

I have a class (Schedule) defined as such (schedule.h file shown)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TdCalendarView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Schedule : UIView  {
    IBOutlet UIView *schedule;
}

- (void) calendarTouched:(CFGregorianDate) selectedDate;

@end
```

Schedule.m looks like this:

```
- (void) calendarTouched: (CFGregorianDate) selectedDate  {

    NSLog(@"calendarTouched - currentSelectDate: %@/%@/%@", selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day, selectedDate.year);
    return;
}
```

In another class, I am calling *calendarTouched* with this method call:

```
Schedule *sch = [[Schedule alloc] init];
[sch.calendarTouched:currentSelectDate];
```

I'm getting a build error, saying 'calendarTouched' not found on object of type Schedule.  (I have an #import "Schedule.h" in the calling class)

I've done a clean, but to no avail.  Why can't it find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call methods like that in Objective-C. Do this instead:

```
[sch calendarTouched:currentSelectDate];
```

Comment: I can't believe it!  Right in front of me and I know better... thank you so much...

Answer (score 4):

```
[sch.calendarTouched:currentSelectDate];
```

You're combining dot syntax and bracket syntax here. This should be:

```
[sch calendarTouched:currentSelectDate];
```

Comment: DrummerB's answer was actually 29 seconds _after_ mine, but which of us gets the checkmark doesn't matter to me. (That's well within the "same time" answer threshhold anyways.)